# React-JS How do I make a preloader icon appear before the image gallery is loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a lightbox gallery coming through dependency `react-lightbox-component`. 
Everything is working fine but before the gallery pop up on the screen I would like to show a preloader icon coming from the font-awesome:

```
<i className="fa fa-spinner"></i>
```

The font-awesome is already installed in my application and working fine. How do I imnplement the preloader with the lightbox gallery?

**React-lightbox-Component documentation:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lightbox-component

**My component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';


class PortfolioPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {     
      resultPhotos: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({  
      resultPhotos: this.props.data.photos
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { resultPhotos } = this.state;   
    const renderImages = resultPhotos && resultPhotos.map((photo, index) => {
      return (
        {
          src: `../images/${photo}`,
          key: index
        }
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <Lightbox images={renderImages} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PortfolioPage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

- I changed the `componentDidMount` in order to set the photos already parsed.
- I also changed the `return` section with two render possibilities.

Hope it helps.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';


class PortfolioPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {     
      resultPhotos: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const parsePhotos = arr =>
        arr.map((photo, index) => ({
            src: `../images/${photo}`,
            key: index
        }));
    const { data } = this.props;
    if (data && data.photos) {
        this.setState({  
            resultPhotos: [...parsePhotos(data.photos)]
        })
    }

  }

  render() {
    const { resultPhotos } = this.state;   

    return (
      <div>
        { !!resultPhotos.length
            ? (<Lightbox images={resultPhotos} />)
            : (<i className="fa fa-spinner"></i>)
        }
      </div>
      )
  }
}

export default PortfolioPage
```

---

**UPDATE**

After a chat with @claudiobitar we found that it was a problem with the dependency `react-lightbox-component`.

```
It is not a problem of the PortfolioPage.jsx, but the Lightbox component.
If it is a dependency issue there is no much to do, sorry, just try another one.
If a dependency has less than 1000 downloads per week is a bad sign.
```

Comment: -**Note:** Also I recommend you to create a separated function with the sections that parses the data. You can use it in `componentDidMount()`, in order to have the data already parsed in your `resultPhotos`.   But do this refactor after resolve the first issue.

Comment: That did not work. The preloader was shown but the gallery did not

Comment: Can you refactory my code with your complete solution? by involving the separeted function?

Comment: It is showing an error in this line:
`const {data}  = this.props;` `expect:','`

Comment: Oh there was a missing `)` in the parse function. Updated.

Comment: Now is showing another error: `renderImage is not defined`

Comment: That did not work. The gallery was shown but the preloader did not

Comment: replace  `renderImage`  with `resultPhotos`

Comment: After I was corrected by replacing `renderImage` with `resultPhotos` it continues not working, showing the gallery and NOT showing the preloader.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195004/discussion-between-nico-diz-and-claudiobitar).

Answer (score 0):

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({  
      resultPhotos: this.props.data.photos,
      isReady = false,
    })
  }
```

```js
render() {
    const { resultPhotos, isReady } = this.state;   
    const renderImages = resultPhotos && resultPhotos.map((photo, index) => {
      return (
        {
          src: `../images/${photo}`,
          key: index
        }
      )
    })

    if (!isReady) return (<i className="fa fa-spinner"></i>);

    return (
      <div>
        <Lightbox images={renderImages} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Here you almost have everything you need, just find the right place where to put `this.setState({isReady: true})`.

Comment: where did I put `this.setState({isReady: true})` ?

Comment: Nowhere, but you have to find out when the thumbnails are loaded and then put the state to ready to re render the component